# Visual Studio 2019 Rename Refactoring doesn't work after update

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, rename, visual-studio-2019

Today I updated Visual Studio 2019, and here's the version info after the update.

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.6.2
>
> VisualStudio.16.Release/16.6.2+30204.135
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.8.03761

After updating, it looks like rename refactoring doesn't work anymore. To illusrate, here's a simple program where I have an `int` variable named `value`, which I then renamed to `aaaaaaaaa`. When I do and hover the mouse over the renamed variable, I get the squiggly line, but in the options offered to me I no longer see the refactoring option to rename other places where the variable is used.

[image]

Has anyone come across this, and is there a known fix other than downgrading?

Comment: This has been identified as a bug by VS dev team and will be fixed in a future release. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1043991/rename-objectvariable-names-no-longer-available-on.html

Comment: This was identified as a bug over a year ago.  I just removed and did fresh install of VS 2019 Enterprise and refactoring is not working.   looks like Enterprise has a ton of settings to "enable" this. Tried them, and restarted. No luck.